# What is the word for something that is made out to be very important, but isn't?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the term for something that is told as extremely important and crazy, but is really generic and bland?

For example, if there was someone who was talking about some sort of life-or-death game with the intent of grabbing the listener's interest, but it ends up falling flat and the listener couldn't care less, what would that be called?

Comment: From the [description of the single-word-requests tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests): To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the few potential words:

**Hyperbolized** (verb): [<sub>Oxford Dictionary</sub>](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hyperbolize)

> Represent something as being larger, better, or worse than it really is; exaggerate.
>
> > ‘victims are prone to hyperbolize and invent details that just aren't there’

**Overdramatize** (verb):[<sub>Oxford Dictionary</sub>](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/overdramatize)

> React to or portray (something) in an excessively dramatic manner
>
> > ‘I succumbed to the temptation to overdramatize my theme’

Sensationalized (verb):[<sub>Oxford Dictionary</sub>](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sensationalize)

> (**especially of a newspaper**) present information about (something) in a sensational way.
>
> > ‘the papers want to sensationalize the tragedy that my family has suffered’

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for ***overhyped***?  From the Cambridge Dictionary:

> ***[overhype](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/overhype)***
>
> **verb** [ T ] also over-hype UK ​  /ˌəʊvəˈhaɪp/ US ​  disapproving
>
> to advertise or praise something more than it deserves in newspapers, on television, online, etc., in order to make people excited about it and want to buy, try it, invest in it, etc.:
>
> *People wondered aloud whether the company had been overhyped.*
> *Probably only one in 20 of these stocks will retain their present over-hyped levels.*

Or from the Oxford Dictionaries:

> ***[overhype](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/overhype)***
>
> **VERB**
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> Make exaggerated claims about (a product, idea, or event); publicize or promote excessively.
>
> *‘the film was overhyped by the press’*

Alternatively, you might like ***overrated***.  The Oxford Dictionaries defines it as:

> ***[overrate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/overrate)***
>
> **VERB**
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> (often as adjective **overrated**)
> Have a higher opinion of (someone or something) than is deserved.
>
> *‘an overrated player’*